# Why is my BCM43142 chipset is not recognised and device wlan0 not found?

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant, wlan

I'm trying to setup the WiFi connection on my Lenovo B590 but I get the following error :

> ```
>   ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured wpa_supplicant:
>   /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start run-parts:
>   /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
>   Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2 Copyright 2004-2011
>   Internet Systems Consortium. All rights reserved. For info, please
>   visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
> ```
>
> **Cannot find device "wlan0" Bind socket to interface: No such device**
>   Failed to bring up work-network

So I looked up which firmware I need so my Debian 7 Wheezy system could find wlan0.

**NOTE:** the wlan chipset is a Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 and its PCI-ID is 14e4:4365

> host@user $ lspci -vnn -d 14e4: |grep Network
>
> 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142
>   802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

I found [this article](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) on the Debian Wiki giving all the steps needed to get it working, I followed them and got no errors anywhere.

I set up the WiFi interface with wpa_supplicant but when I run

```
$ ifdown wlan0
$ ifup wlan0=work-network
```

I still get the error **Cannot find device "wlan0" Bind socket to interface: No such device**

Do you know what is missing for it to work?

**EDIT:** below is the `dmesg` output

```
$ dmesg |grep broadcom -i                               
[    2.574645] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[    6.828086] eth1: Broadcom BCM4365 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.20.55.19 (r300276)
[   10.343512] Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PMNLS ]
```

And here is the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo

# iface lo inet loopback

iface work-network inet dhcp
      wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/work-network.conf

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
```

Comment: Are you using `/etc/network/interfaces`, and if so, can you post the contents of that? If not please state how you are configuring your network. Check also what modules are loaded - you can post the relevant portion of `lsmod` if you want.

Comment: I am indeed using `/etc/network/interfaces`, I will edit with the content of the file.

Comment: This will be easier to debug in chat. You need 20 rep to talk in chat, which you now have. If you want to come over to the main unix.sx chat room, maybe you can get some help there. Ping me from there if you want.

Comment: A likely source of the problem is the device name `wlan0`. Where did you get that from?

Comment: What is the output of `iwconfig`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Sorry for the delay, I had to reinstall my wheezy (for other purposes). `wlan0` comes from the command `ifup wlan0=work-network`, slm and PioneerAxon stated that my wireless device was in fact eth1 (that I tested unsuccessfully, probably because of my wrong work-network.conf).
I will try this again, thank you for your valuable input.

Comment: Ok, but can you state the output of `iwconfig`, please?

Comment: I can not right now, I did not reinstall the fw yet and apt-get is already running. I will ASAP

Comment: @FaheemMitha my Wireless interface was indeed eth1, now that I reinstaled everything it seems likes it is wlan0 and everything is working fine. My issue was that I used wlan0 instead of eth1, the installation of wl and the drivers worked fine. Thank you a lot for your comments

Comment: Good to know it is working. Does `iwconfig` report the wireless device? What is the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system is not reporting a device `wlan0` as available then the Linux kernel was unsuccessful in detecting your hardware and associating a driver to it. I would start by looking in the `dmesg` output for any messaging related to the Broadcom device.

If it's being reported there in any way then the appropriate driver is either not present within the kernel/system or it is misconfigured for your particular system.

#### Finding a driver

Searching a bit on the name of your card + linux yielded this thread titled: [Thread: Broadcom BCM43142 Driver Ubuntu 12.10 64 Bit](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2123154) which has details on how to install/configure an appropriate driver for your system.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I edited my question and added the dmesg output. I stumbled across the thread you linked and already tried it, with no success.

Comment: @ZackDibe - That output is for your ethernet device. It's using driver `r300276`. Is there nothing about the WiFi then?

Comment: It's the whole output of `dmesg`

Comment: @ZackDibe - I think eth1 is your wireless device. Notice the bit that says: "Hybrid Wireless Controller". Seems like the WiFi is being assigned this driver instead: `r300276`. I would do a `lspci -vvv` and make note of the eth1/WiFi device's output from that command.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface name is **eth1** and not **wlan0**. Replace **wlan0** in all commands with **eth1**, and it should work.